# I'm lost, and my outputs are incorrect (C)

Tags: c

So I have an assignment for my class and where supposed to have a structure, two functions, and a main function. The structure needs to have those 3 variables, the functions need to have those names, and the main can only have those 3 lines. This is my first C program and we've been doing c++ all year so I'm  a little lost. I wrote up the program and it compiles, but after I enter the values, the outputs equal a value that's basically random.

```
//Joshua    
#include <stdio.h>

struct Person
{
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float gpa;
};

void fill_person(struct Person* per)
{
    char name[100];
    printf("Enter a name.\n");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    per->name = name;

    int age;
    printf("Enter an age. \n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    per->age = age;

    float gpa;
    printf("Enter a GPA. \n");
    scanf("%f", &gpa);
    per->gpa = gpa;

}

void show_person(struct Person* per)
{
    char name[100];
    printf("The person's name is %c\n", &name);

    int age;
    printf("Their age is %d\n", &age);

    int gpa;
    printf("Their GPA is %f", &gpa);
}

int main()
{
    struct Person per;
    fill_person(&per);
    show_person(&per);
}
```

Comment: Compile with warnings turned on and the compiler will give you some good clues!

Comment: In fill person tou cannot do "per->name=name;" you need to use the strcpy function.  In the show_person function you are not using the pointer passed in - you are declaring valiables, not initializing them, and then printing them.  Get rid of the variable declarations in show_person and then make the printf statements use per->name, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `printf` statements in `show_person` — at the minute they're passing the wrong kind of variable after each string, and the values they're passing are unrelated to the `struct` you pass in.

The stuff around your `fgets` also won't work the way you expect. E.g. `char string1[100], string2[100]; string2 = string1;` doesn't copy the contents of string1 to string 2.

Comment: I have small question. I though he needs to malloc the pointer ?. Dont we need to malloc it ?

Comment: He doesn't need to `malloc()`, he just needs to use `strcpy()`, or even better, read it directly into the struct member.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths thank you. :( I'm still not clear with this malloc thing.

Comment: @Priyatham51: You only need `malloc` when you're allocating stuff.  Since `per` is auto, it (along with the definite-sized array within it) already exists as long as `main` is running, so there's nothing to allocate.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you aren't using the 'per' variable you pass the show_person function. You are basically creating new variables in that function, and then displaying them. You need to use per-> and drop the declaration of the variables in the function.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` and other variables that you're printing are uninitialized local variables. You want to print the name from the Person object instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is better, you don't need to use those local variables, you can read directly into your struct:

```
void fill_person(struct Person* per)
{
  printf("Enter a name.\n");
  fgets(per->name, 100, stdin);

  printf("Enter an age. \n");
  scanf("%d" ,&per->age);

  printf("Enter a GPA. \n");
  scanf("%f",&per->gpa);
}
```

Check Tommy's answer for the problem with your other function.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr "The outputs equal a value that's basically random" *because*

1. `printf` is being used incorrectly; and
2. `per->name = name` is incorrect.

#### Fixing printing

The `&someVariable` makes sense when using `scanf`/`fgets`/etc as these functions must *modify* a variable (in C this is done by passing a pointer to said variable); however, one *should not* pass a pointer to a variable when using `printf`: just pass the value!

Also, *use* the data that has been read (here is is available via the supplied `per` parameter). Using new local unassigned variables (even without `&someVariable`) will lead to unpredictable output.

```
void show_person(struct Person* per)
{
    // Also note use of %s, not %c - refer to the printf documentation.
    printf("The person's name is %s\n", per->name);
    printf("Their age is %d\n", per->age);
    // ..
```

#### Fixing reading

Now, there is another crucial flaw in `fill_person` (does it even compile?). This because one does not "copy" strings in C with `x = y` as that merely assigns a value, possibly a character pointer. Either use `strcpy` or, better, `fgets` directly into the `per->name` character array.

```
void fill_person(struct Person* per)
{
    printf("Enter a name.\n");
    fgets(per->name, 100, stdin);
    // While the following intermediate variables could also be eliminated
    // using them won't affect the semantics of the code.
    // ..
```

I hope the sample stubs above and notes get you on your way!

Answer (score 0):

Because the struct in C doesn't have attributed like "protected" or "private" in C++/java and pointer *this in c++,so you can change the value of member in struct in function. I think you should write the function show_person like code bellow:

```
void show_person(struct Person* per)
{
printf("The person's name is %c\n",per.name );

int age;
printf("Their age is %d\n",per.age);

int gpa;
printf("Their GPA is %f", per.gpa);
}
```

When you use &variable, it's means the addresss of variable in memory, not its value. You should write your funciton like that

`printf("The person's name is %c\n",name );`

Comment: Won't compile, unnecessary local variables, incorrect format specifier in your first `printf()` call.

Comment: And `per.` should be `per->` if you're going to pass a pointer.